# How to search and replace a string with newlines on commandline in a file

Tags: sed, search, replace

I want to replace all occurrences of a text string in a textfile on command line on CentOS 7.2.

```
Search-string: ).\nPORT
Replacement-string: ). \n0 closed ports\nPORT
```

I know, this can be achieved with different tools like `sed`, `awk`, `tr`, ... but I can't figure out an easy way to do this and be able to understand the command (important ;-)). For me the biggest problem are the newlines, without them, it is a very simple call to `sed`. But with newlines ...

Any suggestion with explanation is very welcome.

*edited*

Input

```
...
Nmap scan report for w.x.y.z (x.x.x.x)
Host is up (0.00090s latency). 
PORT   STATE SERVICE
21/tcp open  ftp
...
Nmap scan report for w.x.y.z (x.x.x.x)
Host is up (0.00079s latency).
Not shown: 2 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
|_banner: SSH-2.0-mpSSH_0.2.1
...
```

Output

```
...
Nmap scan report for w.x.y.z (x.x.x.x)
Host is up (0.00090s latency). 
0 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
21/tcp open  ftp
...
Nmap scan report for w.x.y.z (x.x.x.x)
Host is up (0.00079s latency).
Not shown: 2 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
|_banner: SSH-2.0-mpSSH_0.2.1
...
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add an example of your input file and the output you would expect from it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possible way

```
sed '/)\. $/ {
n                          
/^PORT/ i\
0 closed ports
}'
```

Testing

```
$ sed '/)\. $/ {
n                          
/^PORT/ i\
0 closed ports
}' < input
...
Nmap scan report for w.x.y.z (x.x.x.x)
Host is up (0.00090s latency). 
0 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
21/tcp open  ftp
...
Nmap scan report for w.x.y.z (x.x.x.x)
Host is up (0.00079s latency).
Not shown: 2 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
|_banner: SSH-2.0-mpSSH_0.2.1
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `N` in sed to pull next line of input in the pattern space, and then work on two lines at once.

As an example, conditionally pull the next line in when seeing a `foo`, and then do a replacement on both lines. (Note that consecutive lines with `foo` will break this.)

```
echo -e "asf\nfoo\nbar" | sed -e '/foo/N;s/o\nb/od\nc/'
```

Also, GNU sed has the `-z` option that separates "lines" on NUL characters instead of newlines. That will easily allow you to match on patterns crossing a newline, but will result in the string operations to run on the whole input at once, which might be a problem with large input.

The surrounding structure should of course be taken in to account, it might influence the best way to do the edit.

Answer (score 0):

A new version of GNU sed supports the -z option.

> Normally, sed reads a line by reading a string of characters up to the end-of-line character (new line or carriage return).
>   The GNU version of sed added a feature in version 4.2.2 to use the "NULL" character instead. This can be useful if you have files that use the NULL as a record separator. Some GNU utilities can genertae output that uses a NULL instead a new line, such as "find . -print0" or "grep -lZ".

You can use this option when you want sed to work over different lines.

```
sed -z 's/)[.]\nPORT/). \n0 closed ports\nPORT/g' inputfile
```

Please note that your example input has a space after `(0.00090s latency).`